# Maven dependencies for JSF 2 and IceFaces 2

Tags: jsf, maven-2, maven, jsf-2, icefaces

i have a Spring JSF 2 project which is using IceFaces 2, and i made the project use JSF and IceFaces libraries from properties>project facets, and added jsf capabilities to the project, then used a user library JSF 2.1 Mojara, then added icefaces capabilities too,
what i want to do is add those jars for JSF 2, IceFaces2 in pom file as maven dependencies
any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, i was able to fix it by adding following dependencies:

```
     <dependency>
     <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
     <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.0-b11</version>
     <scope>compile</scope>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
     <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
     <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.0-b11</version>
     <scope>compile</scope>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
     <groupId>org.icepush</groupId>
     <artifactId>icepush</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.2</version>     
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
     <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
     <artifactId>icefaces</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.2</version>     
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
     <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
     <artifactId>icefaces-ace</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.2</version>     
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
     <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
     <artifactId>icefaces-compat</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.2</version>     
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
     <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
     <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
     <version>2.6.12</version> 
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
     <groupId>net.sf.jcharts</groupId>
     <artifactId>krysalis-jCharts</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0-alpha-1</version>
     </dependency>
```

and i added the repo:

```
          <repository>
            <id>ICEfaces Repo</id>
            <name>ICEfaces Repo</name>
            <url>http://anonsvn.icefaces.org/repo/maven2/releases/</url>
        </repository>
```

Answer (score 1):

I added the ICEfaces repository to my Maven `pom.xml`:

```
<repositories>
<repository>
<id>maven2-repository.org.icefaces</id>
<name>ICEfaces Repository</name>
<url>http://anonsvn.icefaces.org/repo/maven2/releases/</url>
<layout>default</layout>
</repository>
</repositories>
```

This Maven repository contains the `icefaces` and `icefaces-compat` artifacts
for ICEfaces version 2 and I included them as dependencies in my `pom.xml`.

The following answer describes how to include Mojarra JSF in your
`pom.xml`:
[JSF Maven Mojarra implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798864/jsf-maven-mojarra-implementation)
If your application server already provides a non-Mojarra JSF implementation then use `<scope>provided</scope>`
for the Mojarra JSF artifacts in your `pom.xml` and change the application server to provide Mojarra JSF.